# Using SSL https with socket.io and swift for iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ssl, socket.io

I have set up and can successfully use my socket for a chat application on the iPhone using port :3000.  However when I try to use port :443, I cannot connect.

My index.js file begins:

```
var app = require('express')();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('...path/example.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('...path/example.com.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('...path/intermediate.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(443, function(){
    console.log('Listening on *:443');
});
```

And on the client side, my attempted connection is:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "https://www.example.com:443")!)
```

The socket connection is hanging and empty JSON returned.  Wondering if I need a configuration file or something else to make this work.  If I change 443 to 3000 above, everything works fine but I need to use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is not tied to port 443. This means you can use any of the other unused ports and have SSL enabled. See: https://superuser.com/questions/791218/can-i-use-another-port-other-than-443-for-ssl-communication

Comment: If I use the port 3000 and select NO for allowArbitraryDownloads in my plist the connection is blocked by the client.

Comment: I'm not a iOS developer and unfortunately I can't help you further on. I guess you already did but you should read the documentation for your iOS Socket.io client.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I did read through the documentation and raised a query on the GitHub site as well. Hopefully I'll figure it out.